# variables in Python moving from int to string

Tags: string, python-3.x, variables, integer, global

```
def round1():
    global Rod, Jane, Freddy
    Rod=int(input("please enter Rod's score"))
    Jane=int(input("please enter Jane's score"))
    Freddy=int(input("please enter Freddy's score"))
    print("The loser is")
    loser=min(Rod, Jane, Freddy)
    print(loser)
    round2()


def round2():
    print("are you ready for the next scores?")


round1()
```

I want the top two NAMES of the highest scorers to feed into this for the next round - is it even possible?! Please go easy, I'm not a coder, just a teacher trying to do my best!

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language, instead of language keywords.

Comment: I wish I knew what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Python data structure called 'dictionary' because you want to assign values to a name. That way it is easy to delete the 'loser'.

```
dic1 = {'Rod': 0, 'Jane': 0, 'Freddy' : 0}

def round1():

    dic1['Rod'] = input("please enter Rod's score") #here we add the input values to the keys
    dic1['Jane'] = input("please enter Janes's score")
    dic1['Freddy'] = input("please enter Freddys's score")


    print("The loser is")

    loser=min(dic1.get('Rod'), dic1.get('Jane'), dic1.get('Freddy'))

    for key, value in dic1.items(): #here we loop over the dictionary to find the loser and delete him
        if value is loser:
            print(key) #here we print the key of the loser, in this case a String
            del dic1[key] #here we delete the loser out of the dictionary

    round2()

def round2():
    print("are you ready for the next scores?")
    print(dic1)

round1()
```

**EDIT** Just saw you have a Python3 tag. In that case, as far as I know, you may have to encapsule in the for loop the dic1.items() with a list(). That would make it list(dic1.items()). This because Python3 returns a *view* and not a *list* as Python2.7 does.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass around tuples of player scores and player names.  Since these start with the score, we can call `min()` on them as if they're numbers:

```
def round1(players):
    loser = min(*players)
    print("The loser is:", loser[1])

    remaining = [player for player in players if player != loser]

    round2(remaining)

def round2(players):
    print(", ".join(player[1] for player in players), "are still in the game.")
    print("Are you ready for the next scores?")

rod = int(input("Please enter Rod's score: "))
jane = int(input("Please enter Jane's score: "))
freddy = int(input("Please enter Freddy's score: "))

round1([(rod, 'Rod'), (jane, 'Jane'), (freddy, 'Freddy')])
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 test.py
Please enter Rod's score: 13
Please enter Jane's score: 34
Please enter Freddy's score: 56
The loser is: Rod
Jane, Freddy are still in the game.
Are you ready for the next scores?
%
```

> how might I make the top two go through only using min?

I'm assuming you don't want the list comprehension that separates out the remaining players.  One way we can get rid of it is by making `players` a `set` instead of a `list`:

```
def round1(players):
    loser = min(*players)

    print("The loser is:", loser[1])

    round2(players - set(loser))

def round2(players):
    print(", ".join(player[1] for player in players), "are still in the game.")
    print("Are you ready for the next scores?")

rod = int(input("Please enter Rod's score: "))
jane = int(input("Please enter Jane's score: "))
freddy = int(input("Please enter Freddy's score: "))

round1({(rod, 'Rod'), (jane, 'Jane'), (freddy, 'Freddy')})
```

Which makes sense since there is no particular order implied.

Comment: That is fabulous!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, as an addition, how might I make the top two go through only using min?  Would I need to code this in a different way?

Comment: @user3631273, I've augmented my answer with a set-based approach to eliminate the list comprehension.